# Express JS session is not saved on Promised environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I have a node js with express session in my code. Below is the code

```
s.then(function(value){
    console.log("hello" + value.username);
    req.session.name = value.username;
    res.send("success");
}).catch(function(valuereject){
    // console.log(valuereject);
    res.send(valuereject);
});
```

When s promise is resolved, the console will log the correct username and also send success message. However, the req.session.name is not updated when I tried to access it after ward. Here is the declaration of express-session

```
var app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Fz}*#hE4"fC,h4Sn',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

thank you!

Comment: And your problem is specifically related to using promises? It works when you don't use promises?

Comment: Hi! I found the problem already. I was using the cookie: {secure: true } in a non secure env (not HTTPS). That is the reason for the problem. I set it to false now, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem already. I was using the cookie: {secure: true } in a non secure env (not HTTPS). That is the reason for the problem. I set it to false now, and it works!